# Javascript Netbeans accessing a new class syntax

Tags: javascript, jsp, syntax, html-table

I have a JSP file which includes a table.
In addition, I have a Javascript with a function called update, in which I want to update that table every time I get a new string. I don't know how to access the class I've created for every cell in the table.

singlePlayer.jsp Code:

```
<table border="1">
   <%           
   int size=8;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   out.println("<tr>");
   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
   out.println("<td class=\"+i+j\"></td>"); }   //creating class per cell
   out.println("</tr>"); }  }%>                  
   </table>

   <script>                 
   function update(p) {
                    var MyMaze = p;
                    var size = 8;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {      
           $(.'i+j').text('*');} }  //cant access 'i+j' class 
   </script>
```

question is, if I've created a class 'i+j' for ever cell in the table, how do I access it in my script?

Comment: What you are doing there is to try to target a class named 'i+j', but the selector is malformed. The correct one should be '.i+j'. Also, you are constantly targeting the same string class, which is, probably, not what you want to do.

Comment: out.println("<td class=\'+i+j\'></td>"); should work? for example I want the 4th row and 6th column to be name '46'. thats the way?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the script. There you would rather do $("." + i + j).html("some text");

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<table border="1">
   <%           
   int size=8;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   out.println("<tr>");
   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
   out.println("<td class=\""+i+" "+j+"\"></td>"); }   // Changed this
   out.println("</tr>"); }  %>                  
   </table>

   <script>                 
   function update(p) {
                    var MyMaze = p;
                    var size = 8;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {      
          $("." + i + " " + j).text('*');} }  //and this
   </script>
```

You were simply using 'i+j' string. Actual values were never used. You were always referring one single class. Above changes should make it work.